# RackPick vanishes while Running the Model

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to pick (retrieve) the pallet from storage using RackPick but when i run the model Rackpick vanishes. You can see the links to the model.

1. [Logic After Running the Model]
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvutC.png
2. [Logic before running the Model]
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qoloa.png

Comment: Did you accidentally click on `ignore` or `don't show` in the RackPick block. Check the top of the properties tab.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Yashars comment: You likely either accidentally ticked the "Ignore" box or (even more likely) toggled the "Visible" switch:
[image]

Make sure to not ignore the block and toggle it visible.

Comment: No, i did not check the Ignore checkBox but in the Advance section, the visibility was set to be off ...thanks to you, it visible now.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the answer so others  can find it easier in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote